# Predicting value from multiple independent variables

Tags: predictive-models

I have 3 independent variables (eg - weight, height) and want to predict the change in another parameter (dose) with the change in the independent variables.

The data is collected from patients who are undergoing treatment for cancer. The collected data include the weight, height and other patient parameters. Based on these a complicated computer algorithm gives us the dose to a particular organ. This process can take anywhere between 5 hours to 5 days.

Furthermore, during the course of treatment, patient would loose weight and the doses can change. Currently the only way to know the change in doses is to repeat the whole process from the beginning which is not practical.

I have data on patient parameters and doses on actual planned patients.

I want to use this data to predict the change in doses without going through the actual planning process.

Firstly I want to know what statistical tests / analysis are to be used in the case.

NB. I am a beginner both in statistics and programming. So, any response keeping this in mind would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi charu. I know it can be frustrating of not getting any response but posting the same question that has been [closed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/599326/to-predict-a-value-when-given-3-independent-variables) for lack of clarity isn't the right approach here. You can add further info as to what your objectives here in light of the tests you are supposed to use.